# there is a process running select statement on tempdb database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the Activity Monitor, There is a process(belongs to a single PC) running select statement on tempdb database,it is always running. and i am unable to kill it. What should i do?

Comment: Depends on what you *want* to do which I don't know.

Comment: That's ***you***, looking in Activity Monitor!!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's ***you***, looking in Activity Monitor.

Activity monitor shows database activity. But producing the list of activities is itself an activity. Therefore it appears in the list.

Naturally it will always be shown as running, because at the time it runs, it must be running. Also, if you kill the SPID, next time you refresh activity monitor, it will make a new connection, so you will see it again.

Comment: That's you, looking in Activity Monitor. 

Looking in Activity Monitor is itself an activity which is shown in the list." What does this mean???

Comment: Activity monitor shows database activity. But producing the list of activities is itself an activity. Therefore it appears in the list.